# How to use NestJS Reflector inside a Custom Decorator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am using a `@SetMetaData('version', 'v2')` to set versioning for a http method in a controller.
Then I have a custom `@Get()` decorator to add the version as a postfix to the controller route.

So that, I would be able to use `/api/cats/v2/firstfive`, when I have

```
@SetMetaData('version', 'v2')
@Get('firstfive')
```

But I don't see a clear way to inject Reflector to my custom @Get decorator.

My Get decorator is as follows,

```
import { Get as _Get } from '@nestjs/common';
export function Get(path?: string) {
  version = /*this.reflector.get('version') or something similar */
  return applyDecorators(_Get(version+path));
}
```

Please Help me out here!
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In decorators, you aren't able to get class properties, or do any sort of injection, so you wouldn't be able to get `this.reflector` or anything like that. What you *could* do is set up your own decorator that mimics `@Get()` and uses the `Reflect.getOwnMetadata()` methods, then returns the ``@Get()` decorator. Might be a bit messy, but something along the lines of

```js
export function Get(path: string): MethodDecorator {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const version = Reflect.getMetadata('version', target, propertyKey);
    Reflect.defineMetadata(PATH_METADATA, version + path, descriptor.value);
    Reflect.defineMetadata(METHOD_METADATA, RequestMethod.GET, descriptor.value);
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

Where `PATH_METHOD` and `METHOD_METADATA` are improted from `@nestjs/common/constants` and `RequestMethod` is imported from `@nestjs/common/enums`. This would create a new `@Get()` decorator for you that works in tandem with your `@SetMetadata()` method. If I remember correctly decorators are ran bottom up, so make sure `@SetVersion()` comes before the `@Get()`

Comment: I have added @SetMetadata() on either side for debugging but in above @Get decorator `Reflect.getMetadata('version', target, propertyKey.value);` gives undefined. Any fixes?

Comment: I was able to get it working after a few changes. They are as follows:
- Use `Reflect.metadata` instead of `SetMetadata`
- Change Get return type to `MethodDecorator`
- Use `propertyKey` instead of `propertyKey.value`

All else seem to work. Thanks!
Once you make these change I can accept the answer.

Comment: Is possible to use this method to get metadata from class?

Comment: Sure, you just need to know the metadata key